# NodeJS: throw er; //Unhandled 'error' event (events.js:72) when using child_process spawn method

Tags: node.js

I've made an `node.js` app to list all `.txt` files from a directory recursively and, for each one, do some stuff.

Here's my *app.js*:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    dir = spawn('dir', ['*.txt', '/b']);

dir.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    //do some stuff with each stdout line...
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

dir.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    //throw errors
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

dir.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

When I run `node app.js` via console, I get the error message below:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

I'm using node `v0.10.13` at `win32` environment.

I do this way (*spawn*) because I want to handle `stdout` line by line (the *exec* method release entire `stdout` as one string).

> *** UPDATE ***
>
> By the way, using `spawn` for `child_process` does not guarantee that the output for `cmd dir` will be line by line. I've created a [question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789536/node-js-why-on-data-event-from-cmd-c-dir-spawn-doesnt-output-line-by-line) too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That happen because `dir` is not a executable in Windows. It's a command from the shell.
The solution for your problem is the following:

```
var dir = spawn('cmd', ['/c', 'dir']);
dir.stdout.on("data", function() {
    // do things
})
```

This exact problem was [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4240) also.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this answer doesn't really answer the question - where do we attach an on('error',fn) handler to capture the error (not just preventing the error!).

Comment: @AlexMills There isn't a real question here, there's no "?" :) And the `error` handler should be attached onto the spawned process.

Answer (score 15):

Several things:

- `dir` is not a real executable in windows, so node.js cannot find the program you want to run.
- You didn't bind an `'error'` handler to your child process and the event was turned into an exception that crashed your node instance. Do this:

```
dir.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('dir error', err);
});
```

- Use [fs.readdir](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback) instead. It's a standard node.js API that does the same thing.