# Yeoman generator issues Error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: command-line, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I went to start a new project though Yeoman and it wouldn't let me as it was saying that I don't have any generators installed. Though I have run Yeoman and generated projects with no issues before.

When I go to install new generator's I get this error.

```
/home/darryl/dev/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/routes/install.js:161
  throw err;
        ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

and to be frank have no clue what it means, so any help to understand it and fix it would be a great help.

**Update

okay so the posted questions didn't help. as the error I was getting seemed to have been a red herring as npm had become uninstalled. so re-installing that has fixed the issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17749055. Please indicate that you've already dismissed existing answers if not or search better next time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NodeJS: throw er; //Unhandled 'error' event (events.js:72) when using child\_process spawn method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749055/nodejs-throw-er-unhandled-error-event-events-js72-when-using-child-proc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-installing npm has fixed the issues.